# Making a slider with half-values

Tags: javascript

I have a slider that works well, but it only allows for whole number values. I need one of the sliders on the page to allow half-step increments (eg., 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3). Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is the CSS:

```
.slider, .slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #999;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
.slider:hover, .slider2:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb, .slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb, .slider2::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<input name="newbelief" type="range" min="1" max="9" value="" class="slider2" id="newbelief">
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("oldbelief");
var output = document.getElementById("belief_value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
var slider2 = document.getElementById("newbelief");
var output2 = document.getElementById("belief2_value");
output2.innerHTML = slider2.value;

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a "step" value to the form. So it should look like this:

```
<input name="newbelief" type="range" min="1" max="9" step="0.5" value="" class="slider2" id="newbelief">
```